# Laravel 8 - Insert in related table in model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Whenever I create a "user", I have to create a line in different tables (like account).
I know that in the controller I can create the user and account like this:

```
$user = User::create($user_inputs);
$account = $user->account()->create($account_inputs);
$OtherTables...
```

Is there a way to do this in the model? Always when someone creates a user from another controller, will the lines be automatically inserted in the other tables. Or is it always necessary to indicate it in the controller every time?

Comment: *"If someone creates a user from another controller [...]"* - Is there going to be a case when that actually happens? Your `UsersController.php` should be responsible for creating a User and associated information. You _can_ define a custom method on your `User.php` model that does this, like `public static function createWithAccount($userInputs, $accountInputs) { ... }`, and call `User::createWithAccount($userInputs, $accountInputs);`. Ultimately you're in control of your own code; there won't be an edge case unless you program it.

Comment: I understand that the normal thing is that the creation of the user always goes through the user controller, but for example, I must create users from another controller depending on the data received through our API. Like this there may be new cases with other tables as well, where the creation doesn't depend only on its controller.

Comment: Yeah, for sure! Ultimately though, that decision is up to you; you can define a method on the `User.php` model like I suggested above, or maybe a shared method on the base `Controller.php` class, etc etc. Keeping your code `DRY` (Don't Repeat Yourself) by writing reusable/shared methods is always a good practice.

Comment: So, following your example, inside the createWithAccount function I can create models just like I would in the controller? (Account::create(...))

Comment: Yup! Syntax would be slightly different for the `User::create()`, since you're in the `User.php` class. Would be `$user = self::create($userInput);` (although `$user = User::create($userInput);` would also work, either or), then `$account = Account::create($accountInput);`. Then, you'd simply return those as an array: `return ['user' => $user, 'account' => $account];`. If you needed to create more, just modify and do so.

Comment: Excellent! And sorry, `$account = $user->account()->create($accountInput);`; forgot it was a related call. `Account::create($accountInput)` could work, but only if `$accountInput` included a `user_id` value (or whatever column links to the `User` model being created)

Comment: I always forget about Observers and Model Events; the answers below are definitely a good option too, as long as `$accountInputs` is available via the `request()` object (didn't see how they were defined in the original question, but I assume from `$request`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Laravel observer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers)

```
 <?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\User;

class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the user "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function creating(User $user)
    {
        $user->account()->create([
            // your data 
        ]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use model events for this. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        // This code will be called every time a new user is inserted into the system
        static::created(function ($user) {
            $user->account()->create([ 'name' => $user->name ])
        });
    }
}
```

There are few more events you can use within booted method, the name tells clearly what they do.

```
creating
created
updating
updated
saving
saved
deleting
deleted
```